# Listing Array values of different types and adding them

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to write a program where a user inputs a series of numbers as a string, then the program splits the string into separate numbers, classifies them by type, lists them together by group, and then adds them together. For example, a user enters 1, 5, 3L, 284L, 4.3 and 2.34. The program then lists 1 and 5 together, 3 and 284 together, and 4.3 and 2.34 together. Then, the program displays the number 299.64. However, I'm getting an error. I'll post what I have so far. Any ideas where my problem might be coming from? Thank you.

Here is my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1, 2L, 3.3"  
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)   
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)     
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)     
    at change.NumberArray.Convert(NumberArray.java:21)  
    at change.TestNumberArray.main(TestNumberArray.java:9)
```

Code:

```
package change;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberArray {

    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void Convert(){
        System.out.print("Enter numbers by: ");
        String input = s.nextLine();
        String[] inputString = input.trim().split(" , ");
        int i = 0;
        ArrayList<Long> listLong = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList<Double> listDouble = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Integer> listInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while (i < inputString.length){
            if (inputString[i].contains("L")){
                long temp = Long.parseLong(inputString[i]);
                listLong.add(temp);
                i++;
            }
            else if (inputString[i].contains(".")){
                double temp = Double.parseDouble(inputString[i]);
                listDouble.add(temp);
                i++;
            }
            else{
                int temp = Integer.parseInt(inputString[i]);
                listInt.add(temp);
                i++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Here are the long numbers you entered:");
        for (int q = 0; q < listLong.size(); q++)
        {
            System.out.println(listLong.get(q));
        }

        System.out.println("Here are the double numbers you entered:");
        for (int q = 0; q < listDouble.size(); q++)
        {
            System.out.println(listDouble.get(q));
        }

        System.out.println("Here are the integer numbers you entered:");
        for (int q = 0; q < listInt.size(); q++)
        {
            System.out.println(listInt.get(q));
        }

        System.out.println("Here is the sum of the numbers you entered: ");
        double sum = 0;

        for (int z = 0; z < inputString.length; z++)
        {
            sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(inputString[z]);
        }

        System.out.print(sum);          
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Added it to the original post. Thanks @JasonC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
String[] inputString = input.trim().split(" , ");
```

That will match space -> comma -> space exactly. (A good hint that this split delimiter wasn't working correctly is that the entire unsplit input string was in the error message.) You could use a regex like this to ignore whitespace instead:

```
String[] inputString = input.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

Or you could just split at commas...

```
String[] inputString = input.trim().split(",");
```

...and then use `inputString[i].trimmed()` later.

By the way; after you fix this you will run into problems parsing the "L" strings, as e.g. "3L" isn't a valid integer. You will have to get the "L" out of the string to parse it.

Comment: Thanks! That almost works, but I still get an error when I enter a long number (ie 584L, etc). Doubles and ints work, strangely enough.

Comment: @GoldenEarring See my "by the way" note at the end of the post.